# FFMPEG - AMD GPU Transcoding MJPEG to HEVC provides a skewed split screen video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, graphics-card, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card

Trying to use AMD GPU for transcoding MJPEG to HEVC using VA-API.

Using this command:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -c:v mjpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -vf 'scale_vaapi=format=nv12' -c:v hevc_vaapi -map 0:a? -map 0:s? -c:s copy -rc_mode 1 -qp 25 -map_chapters 0 output.mp4 -y
```

And it seems to work fine, no skipped frames, smooth transcoding, only 2-3% CPU usage. However the video output file is completely skewed.

For some reason FFMPEG splits the video into two pieces where one half of the video is the actually the proper video and the other half is all skewed up.

Here is a picture of the video output:

[imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T86kG.png)

*Note: The camera is a CCTV camera, which is using it's infrared LEDs to view in the dark room. So it is in greyscale color due to the camera and not any issues based on transcoding.*

Here is the output video file:

https://youtu.be/XCC4JDffTxM

Any clue why this is happening?

OS: Arch Linux

GPU: AMD Radeon Pro WX 2100.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What happens when you try storing the MJPEG codec without transcoding: Example: `ffmpeg -y -an -sn -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -framerate 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -c:v copy output.mp4` ? What happens when you are transcoding an MP4 file using VA-API?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for replying. Will try it out thanks.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine without transcoding, I previously tried the below supplied command and it only encodes great when set to 30FPS but uses good amount of CPU resource. When I set it to 60FPS, FFMPEG uses little to no CPU resource, however the video output files does not playback properly and just freezes after 3 secs: 

`ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v hevc_vaapi output.mp4 -y`

I also tried your code example, the video does not play smooth, it just freeze like a picture.

Comment: I'm using VA-API for all commands. AMF encoders does work. I couldn't figure out the proper syntax on supplying transcoding command for AMF. Can you provide a code example on how to do legitimate AMD AMF transcoding? Also, I can do transcoding using two GPUs such as this command with great results: `ffmpeg -init_hw_device cuda=decdev:/dev/dri/renderD129 -init_hw_device vaapi=encdev:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_device decdev -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v mjpeg_cuvid -i /dev/video0 -filter_hw_device encdev -vf 'hwdownload,format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v hevc_vaapi output.mp4 -y`

Comment: I can't test it, I have NVIDIA GPU (and Windows). I just tried narrowing the problem: **1.** Is it a camera related issue? **2.** Is it VAAPI encoding issue? (It could be both). What happens when you are transcoding an MP4 file using VA-API? Example: **1.** Build synthetic video file: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=50:size=1920x1080:rate=1 -vcodec mjpeg input.mp4` **2.** Transcode the file: `ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -c:v mjpeg -i input.mp4 -vf 'scale_vaapi=format=nv12' -c:v hevc_vaapi -rc_mode 1 -qp 25 output.mp4 -y`

Comment: Thank You, I'll try this.

Comment: Alright, I get this error when trying to transcode the synthetic input file: `[mjpeg @ 0x5589220c40c0] Failed to end picture decode issue: 6 (invalid VASurfaceID).
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Input/output error` Here is the pastebin link for what I obtained from terminal: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/r0PZQpSj). Thanks.

Comment: Add `hwupload`: `testsrc=duration=50:size=1920x1080:rate=1 -vcodec mjpeg input.mp4 2. Transcode the file: ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -c:v mjpeg -i input.mp4 -vf 'hwupload,scale_vaapi=format=nv12' -c:v hevc_vaapi -rc_mode 1 -qp 25 output.mp4 -y` (I can't test it so I may have errors).

Comment: Thank You, I'll try this

Comment: I use the same previous command to create a new synthetic video file. Then entered your command: `ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -c:v mjpeg -i input.mp4 -vf 'hwupload,scale_vaapi=format=nv12' -c:v hevc_vaapi -rc_mode 1 -qp 25 output.mp4 -y`. Seems like I get a different error. Here is the pastebin link for what I obtained from terminal: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8q4dF5gK). Thanks

Comment: Sorry that I can't help you. My recommendation is separating the original FFmpeg command into two simpler commands that are easier to test. I can't tell the exact commands.

Comment: Thank You for your help, it is helpful regardless.